# Inserting values into a global C++ set from a recursion

Tags: c++, stl, scope

First time questioner. I realized this morning that i knew how to perform the task of interest by a simple recursive call. The trouble is that the global set was not changed by any of the calls S.insert(n) I put in. I expect there is a straightforward way to rewrite this so as to fill up the set with the numbers found. So, the question is, how to do that?

Here are the function as i wrote it, the fragment that calls it later, and the relevant part of the output. i am entirely happy with the lines from the cerr command, so it is just a matter of getting those values (first and third in each line) into an STL set. My first guess on how to do that part is not good enough.

..............................................................

```
void insert_primitive_reps(unsigned int a, unsigned int h, unsigned int b, unsigned int M, set<unsigned int>  S)
{
  cerr << setw(12) << a  << setw(12) << h  << setw(12) << b << "   insert_primitive_reps"    << endl;
  if ( a <= M )
  {
    S.insert(a);
    if ( b <= M )
    {
      S.insert(b);
      if ( a <= M - b && h <= M - a - b)
      {
        if( a <= M - a - h ) insert_primitive_reps(a, h + 2 * a, a + b + h, M, S);
        if( b <= M - b - h ) insert_primitive_reps(a + b + h, h + 2 * b,b, M, S);
         // comment: once a+b+h <= M, min(2a+h, 2b+h) <= M
      }  // if a + b + h
    } // if  b
  } // if a

} // end insert_primitive_rep
```

.....................................

```
set<unsigned int>  S;

 insert_primitive_reps(1,3,1,100,  S);



cout << S.size() << endl; 


 set<unsigned int>::iterator iterU;
 for(iterU = S.begin() ;   iterU != S.end() ; ++iterU)
    {

      unsigned int p = *iterU;
      cout << setw(12) << p << Factored(p) << endl;
    }
```

......................................

```
 June 7    2014  

           1           3           1   insert_primitive_reps
           1           5           5   insert_primitive_reps
           1           7          11   insert_primitive_reps
           1           9          19   insert_primitive_reps
           1          11          29   insert_primitive_reps
           1          13          41   insert_primitive_reps
           1          15          55   insert_primitive_reps
           1          17          71   insert_primitive_reps
           1          19          89   insert_primitive_reps
          55          95          41   insert_primitive_reps
          41          69          29   insert_primitive_reps
          29          47          19   insert_primitive_reps
          95          85          19   insert_primitive_reps
          19          29          11   insert_primitive_reps
          19          67          59   insert_primitive_reps
          59          51          11   insert_primitive_reps
          11          15           5   insert_primitive_reps
          11          37          31   insert_primitive_reps
          11          59          79   insert_primitive_reps
          79          99          31   insert_primitive_reps
          31          25           5   insert_primitive_reps
          31          87          61   insert_primitive_reps
          61          35           5   insert_primitive_reps
           5           5           1   insert_primitive_reps
           5          15          11   insert_primitive_reps
           5          25          31   insert_primitive_reps
           5          35          61   insert_primitive_reps
          61          87          31   insert_primitive_reps
          31          37          11   insert_primitive_reps
          31          99          79   insert_primitive_reps
          79          59          11   insert_primitive_reps
          11           7           1   insert_primitive_reps
          11          29          19   insert_primitive_reps
          11          51          59   insert_primitive_reps
          59          67          19   insert_primitive_reps
          19           9           1   insert_primitive_reps
          19          47          29   insert_primitive_reps
          19          85          95   insert_primitive_reps
          29          11           1   insert_primitive_reps
          29          69          41   insert_primitive_reps
          41          13           1   insert_primitive_reps
          41          95          55   insert_primitive_reps
          55          15           1   insert_primitive_reps
          71          17           1   insert_primitive_reps
          89          19           1   insert_primitive_reps
 S size  0
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

.........................................

Comment: You are passing by value, so each recursive call gets its own copy of the set.

Answer (score 0):

Help from a friend, plus some hints from looking up "dereference" in my book by Deitel and Deitel:

....................................

```
void insert_primitive_reps(unsigned int a, unsigned int h, unsigned int b, unsigned int M,  set<unsigned int>  *S)
{
  cerr << setw(12) << a  << setw(12) << h  << setw(12) << b << "   insert_primitive_reps"    << endl;
  if ( a <= M )
  {
    (*S).insert(a);
    if ( b <= M )
    {
      (*S).insert(b);
      if ( a <= M - b && h <= M - a - b)
      {
        if( a <= M - a - h ) insert_primitive_reps(a, h + 2 * a, a + b + h, M, S);
        if( b <= M - b - h ) insert_primitive_reps(a + b + h, h + 2 * b,b, M, S);
         // comment: once a+b+h <= M, min(2a+h, 2b+h) <= M
      }  // if a + b + h
    } // if  b
  } // if a

} // end insert_primitive_rep
```

...............................

```
cout << endl << " June 7    2014  " << endl << endl; 

set<unsigned int>  S;

 insert_primitive_reps(1,3,1,100,  &S);

cout <<  " S size  " << S.size() << endl; 


 set<unsigned int>::iterator iterU;
 for(iterU = S.begin() ;   iterU != S.end() ; ++iterU)
    {

      unsigned int p = *iterU;
      cout << setw(12) << p << Factored(p) << endl;
    }
```

.................................

```
 June 7    2014  

           1           3           1   insert_primitive_reps
           1           5           5   insert_primitive_reps
           1           7          11   insert_primitive_reps
           1           9          19   insert_primitive_reps
           1          11          29   insert_primitive_reps
           1          13          41   insert_primitive_reps
           1          15          55   insert_primitive_reps
           1          17          71   insert_primitive_reps
           1          19          89   insert_primitive_reps
          55          95          41   insert_primitive_reps
          41          69          29   insert_primitive_reps
          29          47          19   insert_primitive_reps
          95          85          19   insert_primitive_reps
          19          29          11   insert_primitive_reps
          19          67          59   insert_primitive_reps
          59          51          11   insert_primitive_reps
          11          15           5   insert_primitive_reps
          11          37          31   insert_primitive_reps
          11          59          79   insert_primitive_reps
          79          99          31   insert_primitive_reps
          31          25           5   insert_primitive_reps
          31          87          61   insert_primitive_reps
          61          35           5   insert_primitive_reps
           5           5           1   insert_primitive_reps
           5          15          11   insert_primitive_reps
           5          25          31   insert_primitive_reps
           5          35          61   insert_primitive_reps
          61          87          31   insert_primitive_reps
          31          37          11   insert_primitive_reps
          31          99          79   insert_primitive_reps
          79          59          11   insert_primitive_reps
          11           7           1   insert_primitive_reps
          11          29          19   insert_primitive_reps
          11          51          59   insert_primitive_reps
          59          67          19   insert_primitive_reps
          19           9           1   insert_primitive_reps
          19          47          29   insert_primitive_reps
          19          85          95   insert_primitive_reps
          29          11           1   insert_primitive_reps
          29          69          41   insert_primitive_reps
          41          13           1   insert_primitive_reps
          41          95          55   insert_primitive_reps
          55          15           1   insert_primitive_reps
          71          17           1   insert_primitive_reps
          89          19           1   insert_primitive_reps
 S size  14
           1 =  1 
           5 = 5
          11 = 11
          19 = 19
          29 = 29
          31 = 31
          41 = 41
          55 = 5 * 11
          59 = 59
          61 = 61
          71 = 71
          79 = 79
          89 = 89
          95 = 5 * 19
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

.................................